# The way to go with arrays in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have read the book, and I could see in practice there are 2 ways to set an array. The first one is this :

```
var numElementsInSection:[Int]=[]
```

Which later will give you different syntax for operations such as remove objects:

```
numElementsInSection.removeAll()
```

and you can **also** set an array like this :

```
var data:NSMutableArray=[]
```

and remove objects with :

```
 data.removeAllObjects()
```

I am not sure which is right, why you have the 2, and which should I use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is the Swift version. The second one is the translated ObjC version. It depends. But most of the times you probably want to use "real" Swift code when writing Swift.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one more main difference of Swift Array vs Objective-C NSArray:

> *Swift Array is a Struct*, So it is passed by value which means that every object
>   contained will be copied.
>
> But NSArray are implemented as classes (bridged from ObjC) so
>   they're passed as references.

Comment: Well, actually Swift is smarter than that. It will only copy it when you actually change the copy. Otherwise it keeps only the original.

Answer (score 2):

NSMutableArray comes from Apple's Objective-C types and is used for interacting with Objective-C classes and legacy code.

The newer Swift syntax is probably what you want most of the time.

Comment: Most of the times you can interact with ObjeC classes when you use Swift arrays.

Answer (score 2):

- `var numElementsInSection:[Int]=[]` give you instance of `Swift Array`.
- `var data:NSMutableArray=[]` give you instance of `NSMutableArray` (which is Objective-C type array.)

Both of them are interchangeable. But the methods that you call on them depends on which type of array is being represented by the object. Therefore, you have different names of those methods.